# Soap UI proper trasfer

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to store two values in the same property using property transfer for below scenario:

Response:

```
{
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "expires_in": "3600",
   "ext_expires_in": "0",
   "expires_on": "1502435816",
   "not_before": "1502431916",
   "resource": "https://CY17API.toyota.com",   "access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IlZXVkljMVdEMVRrc2JiMzAxc2FzTTVrT
}
```

I want to store the token type value and access the token value in one property at the project level and pass that property to all the test cases further.

For storing one value in property transfer i use `$.token_type` and `$.access_token` but I don't no how to store both.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved without using additional `Property Transfer` test step if `Script Assertion` is used for the same `REST Request` test step.

Here is the idea:

Extract the required values.
Store them at project level custom properties.
Use [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) wherever those values are need in the further test cases.

Script Assertion:

```
assert context.response, 'Response is null or empty'

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.resposne)
log.info "Token type: ${json.token_type}"
log.info "Access token : ${json.access_token}"

//Check those are not empty in the received response before storing the values
assert json.token_type, 'Token type is empty or null'
assert json.access_token, 'Access token is empty or null'

//Store them at project level
context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('TOKEN_TYPE', json.token_type)
context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('ACCESS_TOKEN', json.access_token)
```

Now, use `${#Project#TOKEN_TYPE}`, `${#Project#ACCESS_TOKEN}` to get the dynamic values of `token_type`, `access_token` respectively wherever you need them i.e., in the further test cases.